# execute function IF criteria is met - wordpress

Tags: php

At the moment i have a function and a filter which shortens titles if they are longer than 25characters and appends the triple dot '...'

However, it appends the dots to all the titles. How can i get the following code to run only if the title is longer than 25 characters?

```
function japanworm_shorten_title( $title ) {
    $newTitle = substr( $title, 0, 25 ); // Only take the first 25 characters

    return $newTitle . " &hellip;"; // Append the elipsis to the text (...) 
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'japanworm_shorten_title', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's `strlen`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Your code would go like:

```
function japanworm_shorten_title( $title ) {
if (strlen($title) > 25){
$title = substr( $title, 0, 25 ).'&hellip;';
} 
return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'japanworm_shorten_title', 10, 1 );
```